# How to create routes with unlimited sub-pages in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Is there any way to capture unlimited levels of URLs of sub-pages. My application allows any user to create any level of sub-pages. In my pages table I have parentID.

```
/{page}/{subpage} // this captures 2 level of pages
/{page} // this captures 1 level of page
```

I want to capture all URLs ranging from

site.com/food/healthy/fruit/red/apple **to** site.com/fruit/organge **or** site.com/grapes **or** site.com/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/j and so on.

what would be the most efficient way?

Answer (score 6):

Sure it's possible. You'd need to explode the captured pages on the slash `/` and go from there though.

```
Route::any('{any}', function($pages)
{
    $pages = explode('/', $pages);

    // Do whatever...
})->where('any', '.*');
```

A few things to be aware of:

1. This route should be placed **last**, otherwise you won't be able to hit any other routes.
2. This captures absolutely **everything**, you'll need to return an error should the page not exist.
3. I'm using `Route::any` in the above to capture any request (`POST`, `GET`, etc), you might want to limit this to a subset of those or only `GET`, that's up to you.
4. As pointed out in the comments below, you can no longer use the `URL::route` helper but you can still make use of the `URL::to` helper. This shouldn't be a problem as it's more than likely you're storing these dynamic pages in a database and as such the URI should be stored within the database as well.

Comment: +1, Really nice trick, it is counted only one param but explode turns it to array.

Comment: Yeah it captures all the parameters into a single string which is why you must explode it to get the individual page parameters. This is why it must be defined last, otherwise it would match any request before other routes had a chance. First in, first out.

Comment: What if `OP` wants to create a route using `URL` class ? How would (s)he pass the parameters, is that possible at all ? Maybe not because route won't match.

Comment: I guess that's a limitation of it, you can't use `URL::route`. You can, however, still make use of `URL::to`, and seeing as these pages seem like they'll be dynamically created the URI for such a page would most likely be stored in a database so using `URL::to` shouldn't be a problem. I'll update my answer and list this as something to be aware of.

Comment: Thanks Jason, after this I'll have an array with params like [food, healthy, fruit, red, apple]. How do I create a URL structure in my controller out of multi-level or hierarchical pages from database using parentID? Like site.com/food/healthy/fruit/red/apple where food is parent of healthy, healthy is parent of fruit and so on. How do I make sure red is really a parent of apple, fruit is really a parent of red etc.

Comment: @Navi you're probably going to have to ask another question. Comments aren't a great place to answer more questions. Cheers!